# Is it possible to use Switch widget in a menu item in my Android app? For example same as checkbox when android:checkable="true", but Switch

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

Is it possible to use Switch widget in a menu item in my Android app? For example same as checkbox when android:checkable="true", but Switch...
The only way I can use menu item checkable state is this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/vibration_options_item"
        android:title="Vibration"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:checked="true"/>
</menu>
```

[image]

But, I feel like it is more intuitive for a user to use Switch widget instead of Checkbox

And when I try to use Switch instead, it shows nothing unfortunately...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/vibration_options_item"
        android:title="Vibration"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can't add switch to the menu. but you can put switch direct in toolbar

Comment: Thanks, but I need to place switch specifically as item in menu list, not in a toolbar. And yep, it looks like there is no direct way to implement that according to documentation..